# Is there a function in c ++ that allows me to render text on my screen that will stay in front of any program in windowed mode?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I am trying to make a simple program that will let me render some text on my screen that will stay in front of any windows I have open. I just starting to learn c++, sorry if this is a really silly question.

edit: Which third party library would be suitable for something like this?

Comment: would you like to learn QT?

Comment: Not in standard C++, since C++ has no concept of an output screen, let alone a GUI.   You'll need to use either platform specific functions, or a third party-library that is designed and implemented to do such things on multiple platforms.

Comment: Make a transparent window that is top most. [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7df1480-2f6e-443f-abf5-c9bf4736c5d8/window-with-topmost-without-focus?forum=vcmfcatl](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7df1480-2f6e-443f-abf5-c9bf4736c5d8/window-with-topmost-without-focus?forum=vcmfcatl)

Answer (score -1):

C++ doesn't provide *any* support for graphical UIs.

If you need to create a GUI you will have to use the platform-specific facilities. On Windows you can use the USER subsystem for that. [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) walks you through the steps of creating a basic windowing application.